# Feign Client: Connection refused: connect

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, feign

I'm working on 2 microservices, the first called `Releve` and second `Activiti`, so from `Activiti` I want to send a `GET` method but I get this error. I have tried to comment 127.0.0.1 in `hosts` file but same issue.

**`Activiti` Microservice:**

application.properties:

```
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=activiti-workflow
#server.servlet.context-path=/api/v2/activiti
server.address= 127.0.0.1
```

Proxy interface:

```
@FeignClient(name = "activiti-workflow")
public interface ActivitiWorkflowProxy {


  @GetMapping("/relevebancaire")
    ResponseEntity<List<ReleveBancaire>>getReleveBancaires();



}
```

Activiti Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/activiti")
public class ActivitiController {

  @Autowired
  ActivitiWorkflowProxy activitiWorkflowProxy;


  @GetMapping("/relevebancaire")
  public ResponseEntity<List<ReleveBancaire>> getReleveBancaires() {

    return activitiWorkflowProxy.getReleveBancaires();
  }

}
```

**Hosts file:**

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
#192.168.1.110 host.docker.internal
#192.168.1.110 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

**This is the error:**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: connect executing GET http://activiti-workflow/relevebancaire] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608) ~[na:na]
```

This is my Eureka Server:

[image]